# Replace files name in a directory using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script for copying an existing directory into another one and there modify all the filenames containing the name of the older directory replacing it by the name of the new one.

I'm using this command, which it works fine

```
find . -depth -name '*foo*' -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv -i "$f" "${f//foo/bar}"; done' bash {} +
```

However, as I must do this for several destination directories, I want the 'bar' string in the above command to be contained into a variable, so I could change the content of the variable in a loop (iterating an array) and copying and replacing these files in a batch.

What changes should I do to the command? I've tried the following, but it does not work

```
app="Workflow2";
strChange="f//Workflow1/"${app};
find . -depth -name '*Workflow1*' -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv -i "$f" "${strChange}"; done' bash {} +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command must be modified as the following

```
$(find . -depth -name '*Workflow1*' -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv -i "$f" "${'${strChange}'}"; done' bash {} +)
```